# Let $G = (V, E)$ be a p-regular bipartite graph, prove that total length of all cycles is at most pm.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a $p$-regular bipartite graph, prove that total length of all cycles is at most $pm$.
I don't know how to start, any ideas would help.

Comment: Hi. What is $m$? The number of edges?

Comment: It doesn’t seem like a complete statement of the question, what is pm? It is easy to construct 2-regular bipartite graphs with arbitrarily large cycles, namely just let G be an even cycle of whatever size you want.

Comment: $m$ is number of edges and $p$ is degree of each vertex.